# coloring of column name in excel sheet using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am storing some files in excel sheet using java. I need to color the name of column. how can i process this. I want to color different columns with different colors.

```
resultMap.put("Question", question);
resultMap.put("Option a", options.get(0));
resultMap.put("Option b", options.get(1));
resultMap.put("Option c", options.get(2));
resultMap.put("Option d", options.get(3));
```

Question, option a, option b, option c, option d are five columns that I am storing. excel sheet is in .xlsx format

```
XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook ();

            // Return first sheet from the XLSX workbook
XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet(sheetName);
XSSFRow row = mySheet.createRow(0);
row.createCell(7).setCellValue("Question");
row.createCell(8).setCellValue("Option a");
row.createCell(9).setCellValue("Option b");
row.createCell(10).setCellValue("Option c");
row.createCell(11).setCellValue("Option d");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
myWorkBook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
myWorkBook.close();
```

Comment: How does that map connect to the Excel sheet? Show some of the POI code you are using.

Comment: @Thilo above I have given the code how the connection happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Apache POI, you can do something like the below, or check this page for additional info and examples: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExCell {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Workbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    Sheet mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet("Main");
    Row row = mySheet.createRow(0);

    Font font = myWorkBook.createFont();
    font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
    CellStyle style = myWorkBook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
    style.setFont(font);

    Cell newCell = row.createCell(7);
    newCell.setCellValue("Question");
    newCell.setCellStyle(style);

    row.createCell(8).setCellValue("Option a");
    row.createCell(9).setCellValue("Option b");
    row.createCell(10).setCellValue("Option c");
    row.createCell(11).setCellValue("Option d");

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Sandeep.xlsx");

    myWorkBook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    myWorkBook.close();

    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

}

Comment: above i have included my code for the excel sheet. can you help out with the required changes

Comment: Do you want to change the cell (background) color or the font color?

Comment: I want to change both of them. cell (background) color as well as font color

Comment: I updated the code sample to show more specifically how to achieve what you need. In general, you need to create different Font and CellStyle objects and define them based on the background and forground colors you need - and then you need to apply the relevant style to the relevant cells.

Comment: Note that you can create "simple" cells using row.createCell(8).setCellValue("xxx"); but if you need to apply style of alike to the cell - you need to explicitly create a Cell object first.